# PowerShell WinForms prevents installing Windows Features

Tags: winforms, powershell, xaml, iis

I'm trying to install IIS features via PowerShell but being prevented from doing so. If I run the code below, the script hangs with:

```
VERBOSE: Installation started... 
VERBOSE: Continue with installation?
VERBOSE: Prerequisite processing started...
WARNING: The plug-in for "Web Server (IIS)" is taking more time to load than expected
```

And yet if I run the foreach loop from a console it just works. This leads me to believe something in the GUI is locking it up. Anyone have any ideas?

```
# Checks to make sure you're running the script in admin mode since the script cannot complete otherwise.
# Bombs out if not otherwise. 
If ( !( [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    ).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator ) ) {
    Write-Host "You are not running in an elevated window" -f Red
    Pause
    Exit
}


# loads .NET framework for the GUI.
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'presentationframework' )
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' )


[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
Title="SharePoint Deployment" Height="580" Width="400" >

<Grid Name="gridname" Background="#FF0070C9" Margin="0,0,0,0">

    <Label Name="SetupLabel" Content="SharePoint Deployment script" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,20,0,0" Height="30" Width="200" Foreground="White" 
        FontWeight="Bold" />

    <Button Name="LoadIMG" Content="Load IMG File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Margin="255,22,0,0" Height="25" Width="100" />

    <Label Name="PreReq" Content="Pre-Req checks/installs" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,65,0,0" Height="25" Width="320" Foreground="White" />
    <ProgressBar Name="PreReqProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Margin="30,95,0,0" Width="325" Height="25" />

    <Label Name="LogLabel" Content="Log..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="11"
        Margin="30,140,0,0" Height="25" Width="320" Foreground="White" />
    <RichTextBox Name="LogReport" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,170,0,0" 
        Height="340" Width="325" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text=""/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
'@


# Attempts to render the xaml code.
$reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml

# Converts xaml into WPF raw format. Bombs out if there's a problem.
Try {
    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Unable to parse XML, with error: `n$( $Error[0] )
    `nHave you overwritten something? Drop your code into Visual Studio, it'll tell you where it's failing."

    Throw
}

# This line here creates variables for everything in the XAML code above where a name exists, and prefixes "form"
# in front.
# i.e. <Button Name="GoButton"... becomes $formgobutton. Use $formgobutton | get-member to see variables of 
# our newly created button. 
$xaml.SelectNodes( "//*[@Name]" ) | 
    ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name "form$( $_.Name )" -Value $Form.FindName( $_.Name ) }


Function Write-RichTextBox {

<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Makes changes to the fonts within the log box on a per amend basis.

.DESCRIPTION
    Makes changes to the fonts within the log box on a per amend basis.

.EXAMPLE
    Write-RichTextBox "Hello World" -colour Blue -Style Italic
    The $FormLogReport richtext box will update with "Hello World" in Blue italic font.

.NOTES
    $formLogReport.ScrollToEnd() will always place the scrollbar at the bottom of the richtext box when a 
    new line is added.
    $form.Dispatcher.Invoke( [Action]{},[Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority]::ContextIdle ) updates the 
    richtext box on the fly. It's a TRY/CATCH as if the box is refreshed too quickly you'll get errors.
#>

Param(
    [string]$text,
    [string]$colour = "Black",
    [string]$style  = "Normal"
)

Begin {
    $RichTextRange = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange( 
        $formLogReport.Document.ContentEnd, $formLogReport.Document.ContentEnd )
}

Process {
    If ( $style -eq "Italic" ) {
        $RichTextRange.Text = "'$Text'"
    }
    else {
        $RichTextRange.Text = $Text
    }

    $RichTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue( ( [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::ForegroundProperty ), $colour )
    $RichTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue( ( [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::FontStyleProperty ), $style )
}

End {

    $formLogReport.ScrollToEnd()

    Try { 
    $form.Dispatcher.Invoke( [Action]{},[Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority]::ContextIdle )
    }
    Catch { }
}
}


$windowsFeatures = ( "Web-Server", "Web-WebServer", "Web-Common-Http", "Web-Default-Doc", "Web-Static-Content",
    "Web-Dir-Browsing", "Web-Http-Errors", "Web-App-Dev", "Web-Asp-Net", "Web-Asp-Net45", "Web-Net-Ext", "Web-Net-Ext45", 
    "Web-ISAPI-Ext", "Web-ISAPI-Filter", "Web-Health", "Web-Http-Logging", "Web-Log-Libraries", "Web-Request-Monitor", 
    "Web-Http-Tracing", "Web-Security", "Web-Basic-Auth", "Web-Windows-Auth", "Web-Filtering", "Web-Performance", 
    "Web-Stat-Compression","Web-Dyn-Compression", "Web-Mgmt-Tools", "Web-Mgmt-Console", "WAS", "WAS-Process-Model", 
    "WAS-NET-Environment", "WAS-Config-APIs", "Windows-Identity-Foundation", "NET-HTTP-Activation", "NET-Non-HTTP-Activ", 
    "NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45", "NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45","Xps-Viewer" )



$formLoadIMG.Add_Click( {

    $formLogReport.Document.Blocks.Clear()
    Import-Module Servermanager

    Foreach ( $windowsFeature in $windowsFeatures ) {
        Try {
            $installwf = Install-WindowsFeature $windowsFeature -Confirm:$false -Restart:$false
            Write-RichTextBox "Successfully installed: "
            Write-RichTextBox $windowsFeature -style Italic
            Write-RichTextBox `r
        }
        Catch {
            Write-RichTextBox "Could not install $WindowsFeature" -colour Red
        }
    }

} )

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Not getting much help from Google so would really appreciate some feedback. Thanks

Comment: When you run this from the console, does this part prompt you? `$installwf = Install-WindowsFeature $windowsFeature -Confirm:$false -Restart:$false`. I believe `-Confirm` is a switch rather than a parameter that accepts values. If you use it, it will wait for your confirmation. It is better to remove it and try.

Comment: @RohinSidharth - Same thing I'm afraid. I added the confirm as a means to try and counter this pause.

As an added bafflement, if the feature is already installed it happily progresses as expected until it hits one that isn't, so I'm pretty certain it's something in the GUI.

Comment: Would you like to try to run the working piece of the installer code from a background job using `Start-Job`.

Comment: @RohinSidharth - Start-Job wouldn't work for me either. It didn't hang this time, it just didn't install.

Comment: Ooh, just thought of something. Are you running the GUI with Admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @RohinSidharth, your comments backed up my theory the GUI was creating the problems.

I built a function to 'sandbox' the job but that wasn't enough, I still had to use Invoke-Command to get it working.

```
Function InstallWinFeatures {


   $windowsFeatures = @( "Web-Server", "Web-WebServer", "Web-Common-Http", "Web-Default-Doc", "Web-Static-Content",
"Web-Dir-Browsing", "Web-Http-Errors", "Web-App-Dev", "Web-Asp-Net", "Web-Asp-Net45", "Web-Net-Ext", "Web-Net-Ext45", 
"Web-ISAPI-Ext", "Web-ISAPI-Filter", "Web-Health", "Web-Http-Logging", "Web-Log-Libraries", "Web-Request-Monitor", 
"Web-Http-Tracing", "Web-Security", "Web-Basic-Auth", "Web-Windows-Auth", "Web-Filtering", "Web-Performance", 
"Web-Stat-Compression","Web-Dyn-Compression", "Web-Mgmt-Tools", "Web-Mgmt-Console", "WAS", "WAS-Process-Model", 
"WAS-NET-Environment", "WAS-Config-APIs", "Windows-Identity-Foundation", "NET-HTTP-Activation", "NET-Non-HTTP-Activ", 
"NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45", "NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45","Xps-Viewer" )

foreach ( $Feature in $windowsFeatures ) {

    Try {
        Write-RichTextBox "trying to install $feature`r"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { Install-WindowsFeature -Name $using:Feature -IncludeManagementTools } 
        Write-RichTextBox "Installed $feature`r"
    }
    Catch {
        Write-RichTextBox "Unable to remove $feature`r"
    }
}      
}
```

If anyone has any idea why this is happening I'm all ears. 
Thanks

Comment: What if you put the installer code in a file say `installer.ps1` and invoked the file from your GUI code?